# Passing data to a customised mat-grid component via props

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material

I am trying to build a component that extends the angular material mat-tree component. The goal is to have a table that has a hierarchy of rows that that can be expanded and collapsed. I have been able to do this more or less and it's working when I load data directly from a flat file within the component. The Stackblitz example shows this in a working state. However, you need to click the `Click Me` button to see the data - not sure why this is the case.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/n4nite-tree-table

What I want is to be able to pass data to the component from the parent component. I have tried variations of doing this using `@input` and the `property={{}}` but I haven't been able to get it to work. What I want is basically as follows:

> 1. app.component.ts calls a service (helper.service)
> 2. the helper service passes back the data for the tree grid the html file
> 3. app.component.html passes the data to the component via curly braces {{}}

Note: In my actual implementation the `helper.service` is getting the data from an API call.

**I also have a number of less pressing questions:**

1. When I moved the code to `StackBlitz` my `mat-icon-buttons` that are displaying the expand chevron have a grey background. I've assume that I am missing a theme or style that is part of my main project. I'd like to know what I am doing wrong and how to correct this for future publication to `StackBlitz`.
2. In an earlier example each of the sub items were slightly indented. I believe this is standard in the `mat-tree-control`. I have messed around with the code quiet a bit and somewhere along the way the indentations were lost. How can I get these back or more specifically what have I done to suppress them.
3. In the component I am using a but of a hack to add an extra `dummy` record at the start of the data that feeds the component. The line is below and it achieves the result that I want. However, when I include a second copy of the same component in my page I notice that the below line has been inserted twice. I expect that this is going to cause me problems and that I have done something incorrectly but I am unsure what?

> treeData.unshift({id:"dummy",name:"dummy", type:"dummy",
>   description:"dummy"});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have update the [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/n4nite-tree-table-1ww6wc). Please check. Hope this helpful.

Pass the data through @Input decorator

```
<n4nite-tree-table [facetHierarchy] ="facetHierarchy"></n4nite-tree-table>
```